# How to find the degree of interpolation?

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I have two quaternions: `A` and `B`. I want to lerp between them.

Given another quaternion `C`, I want to find the variable `unknown`, as seen in the equation below:

```
Quaternion.Lerp(A, B, unknown) == C
```

(Unfortunately, the equation above is misleading. In the scenario that `C` is "out of range" -- i.e. not along the shortest path to get from `A` to `B` -- `unknown` should simply be `0` or `1`.)

How can I do so?

Comment: Math.se might be a better site for this

Comment: @MY_G I want to check my understanding of your question with you: You have two quaternions (A and B), you're lerping between them, and you want to find out at what % through the lerp the result will be equal to quaternion C. Is that correct? (And presumably you want to know how to do this in C# with Unity's quaternion utilities?)

Comment: @doppelgreener Sorry for my late reply. Yes, you are correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is trickier than it looks on the surface for a couple of reasons:

1. Lerping Quaternions isn't the same as Lerping scalars, Euclidean vectors, or Colours.

   You can think of an orientation Quaternion as a point on the surface of a 4-dimensional sphere with radius 1.

   To perform a Lerp between two Quaternions, we draw a straight line between their respective points on the sphere (so this chord cuts inside the sphere, rather than wrapping around its surface). Then we Lerp along this straight line, as though we were working with Euclidean 4-vectors.

   Since the result will generally not sit on the surface of the sphere, we finish up by normalizing it, to snap it back to unit length. This is effectively a Gnomonic projection, so it distorts our nice uniform Lerp along the straight line chord into a non-uniform blend along the geodesic arc on the surface of the sphere. Changes in the parameter `t` make smaller changes in the output Quaternion when t is close to zero or close to 1 (where the chord is closest to the sphere surface), and larger changes when t is close to 0.5 (where the chord is furthest from the sphere's surface, and the gnomonic projection magnifies it out)

   For this reason, when we want a perfectly uniform rate of rotation between two orientations, we'll prefer the more expensive `Quaternion.Slerp`, which uses more sophisticated math to blend along the arc directly. Ratchet Freak's answer is a correct formula to use if you want to work with Slerp instead.
2. Quaternions have identical twins.

   For any given orientation, there are two quaternions that describe it: one with a rotation angle less than or equal to 180 degrees (w >= 0), and one with a rotation angle greater than or equal to 180 degrees in the opposite direction (w <= 0).

   To get the closest intermediate between two given orientations, we'll sometimes need to exchange one of the inputs for its twin, which we can form by negating all four components x, y, z, and w.

With all that out of the way, here's a method to extract the Lerp parameter t from an initial orientation `a`, a final orientation `b`, and an intermediate between them `c`:

```
float EstimateLerpFactor(Quaternion a, Quaternion b, Quaternion c) {

    float aa = Quaternion.Dot(a, a);   
    float ab = Quaternion.Dot(a, b);
    float ac = Quaternion.Dot(a, c);

    // If the two rotations on opposite sides of the hypersphere,
    // replace b with -b. This is an equivalent orientation:
    // if b = (angle, axis) then -b = (360 - angle, -axis).
    if(ab < 0f) {
        ab *= -1f;
        b = new Quaternion(-b.x, -b.y, -b.z, -b.w);
    }

    float bb = Quaternion.Dot(b,b);
    float bc = Quaternion.Dot(b,c);

    float cc = Quaternion.Dot(c,c);

    float denom = (bb - 2 * ab + aa) * cc - (bc - ac) * (bc - ac);

    if (Mathf.Approximately(denom, 0f))
        return 0f;

    float t = (ac * (bc - ac) - cc * (ab - aa)) / denom;

    return Mathf.Clamp01(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all quaternions are unit length, you can get the angle between 2 quaternions by taking the acos of the dot product between them. Then the result is

```
acos(dot(A, C)) / acos(dot(A, B))
```

But this is only valid when C is an actual interpolation between them. To verify this you can add one more test:

```
if(abs(acos(dot(A, C)) + acos(dot(B, C)) - acos(dot(A, B))) > epsilon) return 0;

return acos(dot(A, C)) / acos(dot(A, B));
```

Basically the sum of the angle between A and C and the angle between B and C must be the angle between A and B (within error margin).

Comment: This will be correct for Quaternion.Slerp, since it ensures uniform parametrization of the arc. Quaternion.Lerp does not guarantee this, so its interpolation weights will be slightly different for choices of C close to A or B, particularly when A and B are far apart. (The distortion is least when the start & end are close, and vanishes at the 50% blend mark)

Comment: @DMGregory I added the unit length caveat.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue I described. Take two unit vectors on the unit circle and draw a line segment (chord) between them. Divide that chord into equal increments, then project each subdivision point back onto the circle, gnomonically. The resulting unit vectors bunch up close to your endpoints, even though the subdivisions were uniform and all inputs & outputs are unit length. The same thing happens 4-dimensionally with Quaternion.Lerp. It's not bad for most situations, but it does impact the exactness of the answer in this case.

Answer (score -1):

This is based on a theory, since I don't really know how the subtracion of Quaternions work. But, I will base it on the basic interpolation formula, and the method I'll provide has worked for me on Vectors, since subtraction is a matter of a difference between each component.

The first is the linear interpolation formula, the second a way to get the time t, which is in your case, the unknown value.

[image]

You just need the output, which is C and the initial and final values (A and B respectively). Since the interpolation is linear, it does not matter which components you pass, as long as they are the same axes (in this case I pass all the X's, but you could pass all the Y's, Z's or W's).

Again, this has been proved to work for me with Vectors and numbers, but I don't really know how Quaternion subtraction works, I may investigate it and update the answer. In the meantime, I hope it helps.

**Edit:**

After some corrections from @DMGregory, I realized I haven't fully tested the function, so I solved for t and found the correct formula:

[image]

It is the same formula I found in a book used for getting the Membership Degree on a Fuzzy Logic's System given an input (in your case Quaternion C).

Code corrected:

```
float GetInterpolationTime(float output, float initialValue, float finalValue)
{
    return ((output - initialValue) / (initialValue - finalValue));    
}

void Update()
{
    float t = GetInterpolationTime(C.x, A.x, B.x);
    // Here I use LerpUnclamped in case t is out of range [0, 1]
    if(Quaternion.LerpUnclamped(A, B, t) == C) /// Good to go...
}
```

Sorry for the misinformation, and hope it helps.

Comment: There are several problems here. 1) your "then" line redefines the function f, and is not the correct formula for isolating t. You might mean `t = (f(t) - x_0)/(x_f - x_0)`?. 2) This style of isolation works for scalars, but since division-to-scalar isn't defined for 2-vectors you might need to include a step taking their magnitudes. 3) Quaternion Lerp includes a normalization step, which means it's a little more complicated to invert than the pure affine case considered here.  Also, we now support MathJax, so you can write your equation directly instead of embedding an image.

Comment: You can verify the formula given is incorrect for scalars by checking a case like this:  `lerp(1, 2, 1) = 2` but `GetInterpolationTime(2, 1, 2) = 2/(1+2) = 0.6666... != 1`

Comment: You are absolutely right @DMGregory, I corrected the answer already. I'll check about MathJax, appreciate the commentary.

Comment: Still not correct. Try the same test case I mentioned before: `Lerp(1, 2, 1) = 2` but `GetInterpolationTime(2, 1, 2) = (2 + 1) / (1 - 2) = -3`. In general, when answering math questions, I recommend rigorously testing the formulas to make sure they're correct, so you don't leave landmines for unwary copy-and-paste coders to discover the hard way. I have a draft answer for this question I haven't submitted yet because there's still a quirk for some inputs I haven't quite solved yet. ;)

Comment: Oh, another issue: I notice you've tried to extend your scalar method to work on vectors by only considering the `x` component of the three inputs. Imagine how that behaves if the `x` components are all zero (or all the same value, generally) while the `y`/`z`/`w` components are distinct - considering just the `x` doesn't tell you enough about the whole multidimensional problem to correctly solve all cases.